# REEMPLAZAR un string en SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Reemplazar información en SQL seleccionando una tabla especifica y una columna especifica, asi como una linea especifica. Se los agradecería muchisimo.

Es que he buscado pero no encuentro algo asi parecido.

Comment: Saludos, podrias explicarte un poco mas a que te refieres con tabla especifica, columna especifica y linea especifica..?

Comment: Si. digamos que Yo quiero modificar una palabra que está en la tabla "usuarios", en la columna "clave usuarios", y esta en la linea 10 de todos los registros existentes.

Pero esa misma palabra apacere en otras lineas dentro de la DB, Como le hago para modificar la palabra especifica en la posicion especifica que comento. Saludos

Comment: te sugiero revisar: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp...adicional puedes especificar el lenguaje en que deseas realizar esto como php, python, java, etc.... es mucho mejor si agregas lo que has intentaado

Comment: http://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-string-functions/sql-replace/ <<<< vea ese link estimado, por cierto tu pregunta esta bien pobre, intenta redactarla mejor la próxima vez

Comment: Con `UPDATE` cambias el valor de una columna específica. Si le agregas un `WHERE`, puedes hacer que de esa columna solo se modifique una fila en específico. Solo debes saber como definir esto y además el valor que quieres asignar.

Answer (score 1):

Debes de usar la siguiente query

UPDATE TABLE *table_name*
SET *col1 = val1, col2 = val2, ...*
WHERE *your_condition*